# Laser Collimator For Dobsonian vs Newtonian

Tags: newtonian-telescope, dobsonian-telescope, collimation

Will a laser collimator like the Gosky 1.25 Metal Laser Collimator, [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01M4IVUYG/ref=crt_ewc_title_dp_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=AHQ6VCR020F8X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M4IVUYG), work for a dobsonian even though it says it's for a newtonian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Dob is a Newtonian, so yes it will work.  Strictly speaking the Dob bit is the mount, but it's nearly always a newtonian that's mounted.

Comment: I feel really stupid on this one. :( Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Good luck with the collimation.